# How to show a user-defined data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, show, user-defined-types

So I'm trying to define my own data type which expresses natural numbers recursively, as such:

```
 data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

This function works correctly:

```
 showNat :: Nat -> String
 showNat Zero = "Zero"
 showNat (Succ k) = "Succ " ++ (showNat k)
```

However, I don't want to have to call it every time I want to output a Nat to the screen. I attempted this:

```
  instance Show Nat where
  show Zero = "Zero"
  show (Succ k) = "Succ " ++ Main.show k
```

But it returns an error:

```
• No explicit implementation for
    either ‘showsPrec’ or ‘Prelude.show’
• In the instance declaration for ‘Show Nat’
|
| > instance Show Nat where   |            ^^^^^^^^
```

How can I correctly write instances of 'Show'?

Comment: It compiles fine if you replace `Main.show` with `show`.

Comment: `Main.show`? Uh, that's not a good idea, what this means is that you're calling _your own_ function `show`, which is completely detached from the standard `Show` class with its `show` method (i.e., `Prelude.show`).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Using just "show" (which I did originally) gave an "Ambiguous occurrence" error. I thought I was trying to call my own function (recursively).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The instantiation seems over-complicated. This is enough:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

showNat :: Nat -> String
showNat Zero = "Zero"
showNat (Succ k) = "Succ " ++ (showNat k)

instance Show Nat where
    show = showNat
```

Alternatively, one might like to use the automatically generated `show` using `deriving`:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat deriving (Show)
```

In this case, nats will be shown as `Succ (Succ Zero)`, not as `Succ Succ Zero` as intended in the original code.

Comment: Speaking of over-complicating, `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat deriving (Show)` would also do the trick.

Comment: @anumi The "deriving (Show)" method works (though as you point out, with extraneous brackets), but I had already attempted "show = showNat" and get the same error of "No explicit implementation".

Comment: @A.Morris: Is it possible that you missed the indentation after the `where`?

Comment: @anumi Ahhh, it's not just possible but definitely what caused the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, without the indentation, you are doing two separate things:

1. Defining `instance Show Nat` without implementing any functions in it and
2. Defining an unrelated function called `show`. This is why

   > Using just "show" (which I did originally) gave an "Ambiguous occurrence" error

   there are two `show` functions in scope and Haskell rules don't give priority to one of them.